# Java Button pressing visual style

Tags: java, swing, button

```
JButton button = new JButton("Green Button");
button.setBackground(Color.green);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

With above code, Java remove button's hover style.

Pressing down button makes button's background blue.

But how can Java make button's background never change (in this case keep green) while pressing down it?

Comment: I think you'll Ned to change it via the UiManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something as simple as...

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Hello");
btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
btn.setBorderPainted(false);
btn.setFocusPainted(false);
btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn.setOpaque(true);
btn.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

Which paints a nice green button...

[image: Button]

This has no "pressed" state rendering

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what you are doing, you may be better off making a JPanel act like a button.

Another way which appears to work is to do `button.setEnabled(false);` although it fades the text.

The best way I can think of (I am not sure it is the best) is to do:

```
btnConvert.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnConvert.setBackground(null);
        btnConvert.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnConvert.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnConvert.setOpaque(true);
```

This will make everything transparent except for the text.  You can then put a JPanel with a green background behind the button.

The following code works and does not change when you hover or click:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.green);
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setBackground(null);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
button.setOpaque(true);
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
panel.add(button);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

This is what it looks like when you hover or click:
[image]

Comment: *"//These bounds are just for where I was testing it."* - Then use a `EmptyBorder` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was just using a button from another project and testing and failing until I got this to work. I'll remove that line since it is irrelevant for this question.